# Fingerprint has already been taken gitlab

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys

I formatted my Windows 7 laptop and in an attempt to have git setup working again, I installed git and source tree application.

I deleted the SSH Key from gitlab and regenerated the key using `ssh-keygen`. But when I try to add the SSH Key at gitlab, it throws the following exception :

```
Key is invalid
Fingerprint has already been taken
Fingerprint cannot be generated
```

Because of this I am unable to clone the git repository from the source tree application since gitlab is unable to authenticate the SSH key.I followed queries at google groups of gitlab but none of them seem to resolve my issue. Is there any workaround or steps to get the SSH key accepted by gitlab?

Comment: https://jxqc.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/gitlab-key-is-invalid-fingerprint-cannot-be-generated/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure to cut away everything at the end of the base64 encoded string.
Also remove all newlines so the string contains no newlines.

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Removing the key from DB and re-adding it back worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ohh, it's really helpful. I copy pub key from command line which automatically add new line character. That's why when paste pub key value into Gitlab, it shows such error.

Comment: Did not work for me when trying to add my first SSH key. I checked that there are no newlines and that everything after the actual key is removed.

Comment: Just to add on this, something I didn't notice.  I was copying my key from vim, and it had no newlines, BUT I did have ```:set number```.  If I remove the line numbers by using ```:set nonumber``` it works.....there was no visible difference in gedit, or vim, but that worked for me.

Comment: I made similar mistake when copy from vi, because invalid new lines are added, better copy from a text editor.

Answer (score 138):

In my case; the public key i was trying to add was already used with 'work' Gitlab account and i received the said error upon trying to use the same key with 'personal' Gitlab account.

**Solution** - Add another public key on the same machine and use that with 'personal' gitlab account (both on same machine).

navigate to .ssh folder in your profile (even works on windows) and run command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

when asked for file name give another filename id_rsa_2 (or any other).
enter for no passphrase (or otherwise).
You will end up making id_rsa_2 and id_rsa_2.pub

use the command

```
cat id_rsa_2.pub
```

copy and save key in 'personal' Gitlab account.

create a file with no extension in .ssh folder named 'config'

put this block of configuration in your config file

```
Host           gitlab.com
HostName       gitlab.com
IdentityFile   C:\Users\<user name>\.ssh\id_rsa
User           <user name>


Host           gitlab_2
HostName       gitlab.com
IdentityFile   C:\Users\<user name>\.ssh\id_rsa_2
User           <user name>
```

now whenever you want to use 'personal' gitlab account simply change alias in git URLs for action to remote servers.

for example
instead of using

git clone git@**gitlab.com**:..............

simply use

git clone git@**gitlab_2**:...............

doing that would use the second configuration with gitlab.com (from 'config' file) and will use the new id_rsa_2 key pair for authentication.

Find more about above commands on this link
https://clubmate.fi/how-to-setup-and-manage-multiple-ssh-keys/

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although had to make a small change in config file to point to internal <gitlab.company.repo.com> instead of generic <gitlab.com>

Comment: When you copy link clone ssh, example:
```
git@gitlab.com:accountname/projectname.git
```

Now, for cloning, is not necessary put gitlab.com, only gitlab_2, example:
```
git@gitlab_2:accountname/projectname.git
```

Comment: Thanks! This trick works also on linux.

Comment: Combining with a local git user works perfectly <br />
```git config user.name "Your Name Here"<br />
git config user.email your@email.com```

Comment: This works like a charme on my unix server. I only needed the second host in the config file.

Comment: I am trying to push a branch to another repo in gitlab. My current one is in Azure. I added the new config info and I can run # ssh host and it is added to the known host. But when I try to git push git@host roigin_branch:dest_branch it fails.

Answer (score 44):

Gitlab can use your ssh-key in another account of your past projects for somehow - so, easiest way to solve this problem is to create new ssh-pair, add it to ssh-agent and add id_rsa2.pub to your gitlab account.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

When it ask:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair. 
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/<NAME>/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

Please enter `/home/<NAME>/.ssh/id_rsa2`

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

Comment: A correction: 
When it ask: 
`Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/<NAME>/.ssh/id_rsa): `
Please enter
`/home/<NAME>/.ssh/id_rsa2`

Comment: Not working for me , (Using mac machine ) , error - //fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exist//

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error because I already added this key to another account in gitlab.

Comment: How to figure out which is this other account? Do you know this?

Comment: No.. I logged at my other accounts and check one by one. You should try create a new key and test it.

Comment: FYI I think it also fails when the key is used as a deployment key for a repo. Which is even harder to find I guess.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I already had the public key added on another repo.

Fix:

1. On the same GitLab page (**Settings -> Repository -> Deploy Keys**)
2. Scroll down and click to the **TAB "Privately accessible deploy keys"**
3. Find your "Deploy key" in the list and click the **Enable button**

Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 10):

I tried everything already suggested and nothing worked. What ended up working for me was to copy the public key using a command rather than from a text editor (`nano` in my case):

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

replacing, if necessary, `id_rsa` with my specific key name. The above command works on OSX. Other systems require a different command, and they are listed on the following page: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html.

Answer (score 6):

My SSH key was stored in an old Gitlab account, I removed it and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

## Make a New Key

None of the above solutions worked for me so I backed up my old key and created a new one.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

#osx10.12.6

Answer (score 0):

Text editor could be the problem. Try to open key file with Notepad, not Notepad++.

Also add "ssh-rsa " at the beginning of the key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my public key must have somehow been attached to a specific repository.

I went back and deleted two old repositories and after that it allowed me to add the public key to my GitLab account without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add new ssh key 
The pervius ssh key probabley use by another user .   When somone else use a ssh key you must get this error dint worry create a new ssh key and use theme.

Answer (score 0):

In the same gitlab setting page where you tried to add the deploy key scroll down a little bit and you shall find a tab called "Privately accessible deploy keys". Click it and you shall find the key you tried to add listed there. Just click "Enable" from next to it and it would work !

Answer (score 0):

If all these suggestions don't work:

First of all - don't deal with security keys being exhausted or in a hurry, not to do silly mistakes (my case).

Secondly - copy as GitLab deploy key **public-key**, not the private one (my case as well, despite well understand oh how keys work, just being in a hurry).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have not added an existing Deploy key to any other project before, and I am was not a member of any project.

In order to be able to enable the deploy key for a new project, you need to **add yourself as a member to a project where this key has already been enabled.**

Then in the New Project-Settings-Repository-Deploy keys-Privately accessible deploy keys list, you will see this key and the Enable button.

The answer is found in this documentation
https://gitlab-docs.creationline.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/

> In the Privately accessible deploy keys tab, you can enable a private
> key which has already been imported in a different project. If you
> have access to these keys, it's because you have either:
>
> - Previously uploaded the keys yourself in a different project.
> - You are a maintainer or owner of the other project where the keys were imported.

But if you have GitLab admin profile, it's enough even to have "User" privileges as a member for the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove this SSH key from ur another GitLab account, and then u can add this SSH key to your GitLab account.