# Fingerprint has already been taken - Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I deleted my local Gitlab repository (using Ubuntu) and recreated it. Now I wanted to add a new SSH key so I don't have to type email/pw on every push. What I did:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@email.com"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then added the content of `id_rsa.pub` into the `key` form on Gitlab/SSH Keys. I deleted every old key in the settings and also every key in `~/.ssh/` before. And i still get the messages:

> Fingerprint has already been taken / Fingerprint cannot be generated

Answer (score 0):

Try first `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` to double-check you are correctly authenticated.

Then check:

- your deploy keys (`Settings -> Repository -> Deploy Keys`), as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68477048/6309).
- your other [GitLab accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62218019/6309)